# SqlNullException when table is not null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having an issue when trying to get data from a specific database with entity framework. The only thing that I do is get a list from the database through this simple code:

```
namespace Script.Pages.CRUDScripts
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Script.Bd _context;

        public IndexModel(Script.Bd context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }

        public IList<Scripts> Scripts { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var i = from s in _context.Scripts select s;

            Scripts = await i.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Class Scripts:

```
            [Key]
            public int idScript { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Título")]
            [Required]
            public String titulo { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Autor")]
            [Required]
            public String autor { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("Linguagem")]
            [Display(Name = "Linguagem")]
            public int idLinguagem { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
            [Required]
            public String dsScript { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Vínculos")]
            [Required]
            public String vinculosScript { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Versão")]
            [Required]
            public int versaoScript { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Referência Web")]
            public String refwebScript { get; set; }

            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
            [Display(Name ="Data de criação")]
            public DateTime dtcriacaoScript { get; set; }

            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
            [Display(Name ="Data último acesso")]
            public DateTime dtultimoacessoScript { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Corpo do script")]
            [Required]
            public String corpoScript { get; set; }
```

And I get the following error:

```
SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(int i)
lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, bool buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in Select.cs
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIterator<TSource>.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in AsyncIterator.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor<T>+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator, Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in Aggregate.cs
Script.Pages.CRUDScripts.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in Index.cshtml.cs
+
            Scripts = await i.ToListAsync();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory+NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

It is especially odd because I can successfully add data to the database, and also because it worked fine before. Looks like there's a problem with the variable _context, and only with searching in table Scripts, the other tables in my database work just fine. Appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: Added the databse class, does that help?

Comment: It is not a complete example, no.

Comment: Not really. We need a way to reproduce the error as easily as possible. For example, we need the Page's code and how you are calling that method, from where you get `context`, etc.

Comment: From the exception call stack looks like some of the `string` columns marked as `[Required]` (`titulo`, `autor`, `dsScript`, `vinculosScript`, `refwebScript`, `corpoScript`) actually allow and has NULL values in the database.